# Example of a module whose support is not closed?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The support of a module is closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13661/the-support-of-a-module-is-closed)

Is there a simple example of a module $M$ of a Noetherian commutative ring $R$ such that $\operatorname{Supp}(M)\subset\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ is *not* closed?

When typing this question, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13661/the-support-of-a-module-is-closed) popped up.

So I think we can take $R=\mathbb{Z}$, and let $M=\bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}\in S}\mathbb{Z}/\mathfrak{p}$ for a nonclosed subset $S$ of $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$.

Is there an actual explanation as to why the support of such $M$ is not closed in $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$? I didn't gather one from the original answer.

(I don't mind seeing a completely different example either, I just figured I'd ask about this one since it's already here.)

Comment: P.S. With your reputation, you should be able to leave a comment in that answer. You could have followed up with a comment asking why the support is not closed, instead of asking a brand new question. (Clicking on Mariano's name would have revealed he is still active, so he would have seen your comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $(\mathbb{Z}/\mathfrak{p})_{\mathfrak{q}}=(0)$ whenever $\mathfrak{p}\neq \mathfrak{q}$, and $(\mathbb{Z}/\mathfrak{p})_{\mathfrak{p}} = \mathbb{Z}/\mathfrak{p}$.  Moreover, localization commutes with direct sums, so for every $\mathfrak{q}$,
$$M_\mathfrak{q} = \left(\bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}\in S}\mathbb{Z}/\mathfrak{p}\right)_{\mathfrak{q}} = \bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}\in S}(\mathbb{Z}/\mathfrak{p})_{\mathfrak{q}}.$$

So the support of $M$, that is, the set of primes $\mathfrak{q}$ such that $M_{\mathfrak{q}}\neq 0$ is precisely $S$, which by assumption is not closed.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: This does work only if $S$ contains only maximal ideals.